# Unable to Deploy MetaData using Workbench/ANT

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, deployment-api

I'm trying to deploy a metadata package using the migration tool of workbench/ANT with no success.
In both cases, I got "Maximum size of request reached" error message.
The package file size is 80 mb.
Can some shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're unfortunately hitting up against a hard limit on the Metadata API of 50MB packages. The limits are documented by Salesforce at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_metadata.htm

Can you split your deployment in two?

Comment: Hi, I can't split it. Does Eclipse has the same limitation?

Comment: Yes, anything that is built on the Metadata API has the same limitation. That is ANT, the Force.com IDE and any of the third party providers